# What is missing to copy a sheet to another sheet? Not all rows included when current Sub is run

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA.  When trying to copy a sheet, not all rows are included when the Sub is run.  The number of rows in the source document is variable so I have used "LastRow".  Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
    Sub CopySheetsl()

        Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
        Dim LastRow As Long

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("L:\x\Y\z\xxx.xlsx")
        Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro x v.01.xlsm")

        LastRow = range("A:Y").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        wb1.Sheets("Detail").range("C1", "AN1" & LastRow) = wb.Sheets("Detail_2").range("A1", "AL1" & LastRow).Value

        wb.Close
   End Sub
```

Comment: You are copying way to many lines (once you found LastRow correctly). If LastRow is 15 for example, `"AL1" & LastRow` becomes `"AL115"`. The `&` joins to strings, it doesn't "add" lines or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is probably this line.

```
LastRow = range("A:Y").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Try explicitly referencing the workbook and sheet you want to copy from.

```
LastRow = wb.Sheets("sheet name here").range("A:Y").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

If you don't then it is going to look at whatever sheet you are active to in a given workbook.

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help.  Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. After looking at it again the comment from arcadeprecinct is valid as well. You are pulling in extra blank rows by concatenating AL1 and AN1 with LastRow. Just take out the 1 and it should be good.